# Script to select, update, insert and delete from MySQL with asp.net (VB)?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net, asp-classic, vbscript

I've just switched from classic ASP to .net and I always used the following to SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE from my MySQL databases:

```vb
' Create db connection
Function dbConn()
    Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConn.Open "driver=x;Server=x;Port=x;Option=x;Database=x;Uid=x;Pwd=x"
    Set dbConn = objConn
End Function

' Store data in array
Function SQL(myCommand,strSQL)
    Set objConn = dbConn()
    If myCommand = 0 Then
        Set objRS = objConn.Execute(strSQL)
        If NOT objRS.EOF Then arrRS = objRS.GetRows Else arrRS = Null
    Else
        Set objRS = objConn.Execute(strSQL,,128)
    End If
    Set objRS = Nothing : Set objConn = Nothing
End Function
```

For example, to use SELECT I'd just go:

```
Call SQL(0,"SELECT * FROM Users")
```

And to display the data:

```
If IsArray(arrRS) Then
    For i = 0 to UBound(arrRS,2)
        Response.Write(arrRS(0,i) & ", " & arrRS(1,i))
    Next
End If
```

And to insert, update or delete I'd use:

```
Call SQL(1,"DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserID = 1")
```

Does anyone know if this is possible with ASP.Net - VB?
Or is there an even handier solution?

Cheers.

Comment: take a look at ado.net or EDM, ado.net - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8477/Using-ADO-NET-for-beginners

Comment: Not being a smart ass here, but you really should pick up a book on ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC; It's *very* different from classic ASP, and you can't get by just fumbling with asking questions every time you hit a confusing concept, because it will happen constantly.

Comment: A function that just accepts an sql string and returns data is a known anti-pattern. You should not do that. The reason is that it forces use to use string concatenation to substitute data into your queries... in other words, it creates sql injection security issues, and that's a **big deal**... you shouldn't ignore this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can certainly do that with VB.NET.  VB.NET supports almost everything ASP classic and vbscript could do.  ADO.NET supports almost everything ADO did.

... not that you'd want to do it.

I strongly suggest that you look into the pattern and practices that ASP.NET allows.  The newer methods are much better than the old ones.